# how to declare variable on 2 class

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 class like this that try to connect to mysql

these 2 class have same method some are not same.

```
if (isRemote)
{
    RemoteMySQL mySql = new RemoteMySQL();
}
else
{
    MySQL mySql = new MySQL();
}
mySql.Connect();
```

when I declare `mySql` like this `mySql.Connect();` is error doesn't exit in current context.

Comment: Yes, mySql does not exist in the context you are using it. You are defining them inside the braces and so outside those braces, they are not recognized.

Comment: If inheritance is not an option you could also define an interface say IConnectable with a Connect method and let both classes implement this interface. This way you could declare a variable of type IConnectable outside your if block and set it inside your if or else block.

Answer (score 4):

I will use Factory design pattern in your case. The code will be like...

```
    public interface IMySql
    {
        void Connect();
    }
    class RemoteMySQL : IMySql
    {
        public void Connect()
        {}
    }

    class MySQL : IMySql
    {
        public void Connect()
        { }
    }
```

In Factory.cs,

```
public IMySql Factory(bool isremote)
        {

            if (isremote)
                return new RemoteMySQL();

            else
                return new MySQL();
        }
```

So, when you want to consume the Factory, you could use the code as:

```
var mysql = Factory(true);// remote case
mysql.Connect()
```